# Why is this regex playing up?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've written this function:

```
function contain_special($string){
# -- Check For Any Special Chars --
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/',$string)){
# - Special Chars Were Found -
return true;    
}//end of special chars found
else{
# - String Does Not Contain Special Chars -
return false;   
}//end of else - does not contain special chars 
}//end of function
```

To check if a string contains special chars.

The function is supposed to ignore alphanumeric chars and look for special chars. If found, return `true`, else, return `false`.

Now all works well when testing it with most special chars:

```
$text="sdfs-df";

var_dump(contain_special($text));//returns true because "-" was found
```

BUT, when I have a `$` that is not in a certain position of the string, the function fails to pick it up:

```
$text="sdfsdf$";//this works
$text="sdf$sdf";//this does not work
$text="$sdfsdf";//this works
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Mixed single-line comment syntax. The bane of my existence.

Comment: Use single quotes, else the use of `$` could be treated as a variable.

Comment: @BoltClock Is the way I comment bad?

Comment: Well, it's generally considered good practice to stick to one way of single-line commenting and be consistent with it.

Comment: Use single quotes or escape the dollar sign if you need to use double quotes.

Comment: @BoltClock I see. The way I see it is: [`# --` = do something] [`# -` = explaining something] [`//` = ending blocks] - That's how I was taught at school.

Comment: @navnav: Ah, that's fascinating. If it helps you in your learning I guess it's fine, but when writing code seen by many eyeballs, just keep in mind it *might* just be a turn off for some ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `echo $text`. You may not be using the string you think you are. Literal dollar signs often need to be escaped in double-quoted strings so that you're not using the variable, `$sdfsdf`, for example.

I'd recommend just using single quotes here.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

`^` is for start of string. Ok - it also negates the interval(but you do not need to negate - just switch true and false)

`$` is for end of string.

`*` means zero ore more times.

So I think that the regex you want is:
`\^[a-z0-9]*$\`

Does that work?

Comment: This accomplishes the same thing in the opposite way. Asker's regex finds if special character exists; yours tests the the entire string is alphanumeric.

Comment: @Wiseguy: yes - I see now. Made an edit. But does this give same problem?

Comment: Ok - @georgefox already found the real problem :o) ... variable substitution.

Comment: Actually, I pointed out the problem first in the comments. ;-) But no, there's nothing wrong with your regex; it's just a different way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

the dollars in double quotes start a variable substitution, unless they are not followed by a char that validly starts a variable name.
This explains why `$text="sdfsdf$"` works and `$text="sdf$sdf"` does not.
Your last example may work if you have a variable named `$sdfsdf`.